# Orbeon adds namespace declarations to XML automagically

Tags: orbeon

I do not want namespace declarations used during xforms processing to be added to the XML instances I work with, but Orbeon adds these declarations automatically (I do not yet know whether these are added during XForms processing stage, by XForms Runner or by the XPL processor) - I would like the XML instances I work with to be left alone (no automatic insertion of namespace declarations) - how do I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Is this with an embedded instance?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` on your `<xforms:instance>`, which has a behavior somewhat similar to the [attribute of the same name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#lre-namespaces) in XSLT.